# Database entry not created in autoform meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have implemented the following code from [insert autoform](http://autoform.meteor.com/insertaf)

```js
Schemas = {};

Template.registerHelper("Schemas", Schemas);

Schemas.Person = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    index: 1,
    unique: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    optional: true
  }
});

var Collections = {};

Template.registerHelper("Collections", Collections);

People = Collections.People = new Mongo.Collection("People");
People.attachSchema(Schemas.Person);

Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  return People.find();
});

People.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
{{#autoForm id="afInsertDemo" type="insert" collection=Collections.People}}
  <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='firstName'}}has-error{{/if}}">
    <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='firstName'}}</label>
    {{> afFieldInput name='firstName'}}
    {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='firstName'}}
    <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='firstName'}}}</span>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='lastName'}}has-error{{/if}}">
    <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='lastName'}}</label>
    {{> afFieldInput name='lastName'}}
    {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='lastName'}}
    <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='lastName'}}}</span>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='age'}}has-error{{/if}}">
    <label class="control-label">{{afFieldLabelText name='age'}}</label>
    {{> afFieldInput name='age'}}
    {{#if afFieldIsInvalid name='age'}}
    <span class="help-block">{{{afFieldMessage name='age'}}}</span>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Person</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Form</button>
  </div>
{{/autoForm}}
```

Database entries are not being created, where am I going wrong.

Comment: Not sure, but try setting Autoform.debug = true in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to 2_collections.js in common folder and it works fine.

```js
People.allow({
  insert: function () {
    return true;
  },
  remove: function () {
    return true;
  }
```